# Wait until WebElements become clickable

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to map several Elements and when map `WebElement` i am waiting until the element become clickable in this way:

```
val driver: WebDriver...
var wait: WebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
val element: WebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[id=Email]")))
```

Now in case i want to find several elements and using `FindElements` instead of 1 element what will be the code ?

I try:

```
val elements: WebElements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("locator")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`

```
val elements: List[WebElement] = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("locator"))).toList
```

As a side note, to wait for element to be clickable you can use `elementToBeClickable`

```
val element: WebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id=Email]")))
```

For more expected conditions refer [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

Comment: Expression of type util.List[WebElement] doesnt conform to expected type List[WebElement], this is because i am using Scala ?

Comment: @davidhol Actually I don't know Scala, I googled how to define List in Scala. `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` is returning list of WebElement (`List<WebElement>` in Java).

Comment: @davidhol, you should do this in order to fix this little trouble with conversion:
Add following to imports:

`import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Then in your code you can just cast as e.g.:
 `val films: List[Any] = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='filmo-category-section'][1]/div[contains(@class, 'filmo-row')]/b/a")).toList`

Comment: But how to do that with until ?

Comment: @davidhol Exactly as in my answer, just add `.toList` at the end (added in the answer as well). `wait.until` returns the element/s it was waiting for.